# Java conflict : Java was started but returned exit code 13

Tags: eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse Juno is installed on my laptop to implement android app.  Then the same eclipse juno version has been used to set up phonegap.  Now eclipse can't opened, the popup dialog error shows the error:

[image]

In "eclipse.ini" file i added this line

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

to solve the issue.

My eclipse.ini file is as follows:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Eclipse was restarted and i end up with another error

Java was started but returned exit code 13.

[image]

An hour attempt to resolve the issue was unsuccessful.

Can someone help me to find a quick fix.

This is my current Jre version using command prompt java -version.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are pointing to a 64bit version of java (in your *Program Files* and not in *Program Files (x86)*), but the architecture of your Eclipse is 32 bit (arch=x86).

Point to a 32 bit Java in your eclipse.ini instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it looks like problem is with your eclipse version. I suggest you to download 64 bit of version. If you face same issue again, follow steps below:

-Make sure that you have Eclipse 64 bit version.
 -Download and install the 64-Bit Java version form here http://www.java.com/download/manual.jsp.
 - Add the following two lines to your eclipse.ini file (just before the “-vmargs” line): -vm c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

or sometimes c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\ (Path of your JRE) will also work.